# How to modify a existing cookie value for a specific domain using javascript?

Tags: javascript, cookies

I use this method to reset the cookie value but the method creates new cookie and modifies the same,

```
   document.cookie="leo_auth_token=" + cookievalue;
```

This does not set the value for the `leo_auth_token` i think since this cookie name comes under linkedin.com folder in cookies section.

so how to modify for a specific `domain` or under a folder like `linkedin.com`

Please help me how to go about.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set a cookie for another domain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6761415/how-to-set-a-cookie-for-another-domain)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot set the value of a cookie defined on another domain. This would be a huge security risk, and there's a good reason why you **can't** do this!

You will need to find an alternative solution, I'm afraid.

Comment: thanks for the reply my problem is 1. i login using my java webapp to linkedin and come back to my java webapp.2.when i type linkedin.com than the linkedin page gets opened with the user who loggedin using java web app. to avoid this i just want to modify the cookie value so that the scope is not maintained outside javaweb application.

Comment: I'm sure you could use cURL for this.

Comment: can we use uURL in java script or in java?