# From javascript, adding domain or expires to my cookie will not create the cookie

Tags: javascript, cookies

Currently I have the cookie to be added as:

```
document.cookie="key=value".concat(";path=/");
```

And this will add a cookie with no host information. However if I changed to:

```
document.cookie="key=value".concat(";path=/;domain=.mydomain.ca");
```

The cookie will not be generated. Similarly, if I have "expires=" in the cookie it will also not be generated.

I am running on localhost, and I am not sure if there any restriction on what domain I can use? Or what else could cause failure on setting the cookie?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set a cookie for another domain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6761415/how-to-set-a-cookie-for-another-domain). The [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) also [applies to `document.cookie`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.cookie#Notes).

Comment: @JonathanLonowski The diference is that I am trying to set cookie for subdomains (have a dot before mydomain.ca), not for a total srtanger domain. I have the impression that this is possible. CORS may be the  reason, I would appreciate if you can provide answer on how to set the cookie when working on localhost.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski And if it is due to CORS - why would the expires time also disable the cookie as well? Does CORS affect the "expires" on cookie as well?

Answer (score 0):

I feel like this should be in a comment, but I can't comment (need at least 50 reps) so: have you tried setting an expiration date on the cookie? After setting the cookie, can you provide us with the output of doing

```
window.alert(document.cookie);
```

I tried the code in jsFiddle and it worked:
http://jsfiddle.net/8fy24pbu/

Also, your domain shouldn't be localhost because you are not running this from a http server

Comment: I tried this and returned a totally blank screen - I suspect this relating to CORS as Jonathan mantioned in his comment.

Comment: What is your domain name that you are using? `localhost`? `127.0.0.1`?

Comment: Opened in local file sctructure: file:///C:.../index.html#/home and when setting domain, uses domain=localhost

Comment: using localhost means you are running a http server on the computer and you have the url in your browser to localhost

Comment: What os are you using?

Comment: OS is windows 8 and browser is firefox.

Comment: Then try using Apache to run a http server.

Comment: Then you can use localhost as the domain