# Setting Cookies across sub domain javascript pitfall

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, cookies

Assistance is required on enabling a cookie to be used cross sub domains. Unable to set the cookie to correct value in javascript. I am not sure if Javascript is failing to set the cookie or MVC.NET is rejecting the request cookie.

**Browsers not working**

- Chrome 43 (Windows)
- Firefox 38 (Windows)
- iOS 8 Safari

When setting my `web.config` to use `<httpCookies domain=".adomain.com" />` things start to go horribly wrong.

I have some javascript code, in conjuction with pickadate.js datepicker which changes the cookie value to the date selected by a user.

**Javascript Function**

```
// Call pickadate API to retrieve selected date
var dateString = this.get('select', 'dd/mm/yyyy');

var cd = new Date();
var exp = cd.setMinutes(cd.getMinutes() + 10)

setCookie("_date", dateString, new Date(exp), "/", ".adomain.com");

window.location.reload();

function setCookie(name, value, expires, path, theDomain, secure) {
    value = escape(value);
    var theCookie = name + "=" + value +
    ((expires) ? "; expires=" + expires.toGMTString() : "") +
    ((path) ? "; path=" + path : "") +
    ((theDomain) ? "; domain=" + theDomain : "") +
    ((secure) ? "; secure" : "");
    document.cookie = theCookie;
}
```

**What .NET is doing when it receives the request**
Once the datepicker has been changed, it will refresh to page, sending a new request with the date in the cookie. This is picked up a MVC.NET controller. However, the cookie is not changing on the clientside.

```
    if(this.ControllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies.AllKeys.Contains("_date"))
{
     cookie.Value =   this.ControllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies[sessionDate].Value;

     // Do some logic with date to retrieve products

} else {
     // Set cookie.value to today's date
}

cookie.HttpOnly = false;
cookie.Path = "/";
cookie.Secure = true;

this.ControllerContext.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Set(cookie);
```

The http request contains the following duplicate for _date:

```
_date=30/07/2015; 
_date=31/07/2015;
```

but the date should equal 31/07/2015, but i have duplicates. The domains are different in the chrome resouce tab.

_date=30/07/2015; domain=.adomain.com   << I NEED IT TO BE THIS DOMAIN SETTING
_date=30/07/2015; domain=sub.adomain.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While I am not a .NET expert, It is possible to explicitly specify the domain for the cookie in the Set-Cookie header. As per [RFC 6265](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-4.1.2.3), if you specify the domain in the header as `example.com` then the cookie would be also available to `www.example.com` and `subdomain.example.com`. Subdomains are not considered as external domains and hence it is not a security violation.

Probably adding something like this before sending the cookie in your controller should work

`cookie.Domain = "adomain.com";`

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible because of security reasons. [detailed info here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6761415/how-to-set-a-cookie-for-another-domain)

You could try using an iFrame to set the cookie like [Facebook does this](http://nfriedly.com/techblog/2010/08/how-facebook-sets-and-uses-cross-domain-cookies/).