# How to change the PHPSESSID cookie domain?

Tags: php, session, session-cookies

I have 2 subdomains **sub1.domain.com** and **sub2.domain.com**

sub1 is the one to set the login session but the session was not shared because they have different cookie domain

```
sub1's cookie domain => .sub1.domain.com

sub2's cookie domain => .sub2.domain.com
```

**Option 1:** to change sub2's `.sub2.domain.com` into `.sub1.domain.com` so that they can share session

**Option 2:** to change sub1's `.sub1.domain.com` to `.domain.com`

I would want the option 1 because we're trying to avoid changes on sub1.domain.com and domain.com as possible.

I have tried this codes on sub2's end but no luck

```
ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.sub1.domain.com');
session_set_cookie_params (0,'/','.sub1.domain.com');
```

Comment: You [cannot set cookies for another domain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6761415/how-to-set-a-cookie-for-another-domain). However I see no reason option 2 would not work.

Comment: You cannot set cookies for a *different* domain, but you can set cookies for a higher-level domain, which would work here.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot set `session.cookie_domain` to a different subdomain, but you can set it to `.domain.com` and it will be visible on all subdomains:

```
ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.domain.com');
```