# Passing cookie from one domain to other

Tags: javascript, php, web, web-applications, web-deployment

I am making a WebView app and I want to pass a cookie from one domain to other, e.g. `abc.com` to `xyz.com`.

I have both PHP and JS access where the cookie is stored and on the other side I have only JS access.

Comment: Do you mean third-party cookies?

Comment: No cookie will be generated on abc.com and I want to set it for xyz.com

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set a cookie for another domain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6761415/how-to-set-a-cookie-for-another-domain)

Answer (score 0):

Well, as you may know its not possible to set a cookie which be accessible on two quite different domains.
But it has some other tricks. What I came up is top send your cookie  from one domain with cross domain AJAX or some simple web service to another domain and upon recieve set the cookie on targeted domain.

**Cookie on abc.com**   ->  **send cookie via web service to xyz.com** -> **recive cookie and set cookie on xyz.com**