# How to create cookie in ajax calling page in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, cookies

I am using ajax with PHP
I want to create cookie on ajax calling page
i have tow domain
like
domain1.com and domain2.com
i have done ajax coding on domain1.com in page test1.php
And Create Cookie on domain2.com page test.php

test1.php /// domain1.php

```
$.ajax({
     url:domain2.com/test.php,
     type:post,
     datatype:json,
     data:'uname=test',
     success:function(data){
     if(data=='ok'){
          window.location='http://domain2.com/cookietest.php'
       }
     }
     });
```

test.php ///// domain2.com

```
   $uname=$_POST['uname'];
    if($uname=='test'){
      setcookie('testcookie',$uname,time()+3600);
      echo 'ok';
      }else{
         echo 'not'
        }
```

I checked cookie value on domain2.com

cookietest.php ///// domain2.com

```
        <?php
            var_dump($_COOKIE);
                 ?>
```

I did not found created cookie details.
can anyone help me

Comment: This is expected behaviour. `test.php` creates the cookie on `domain1.com`, so it cannot be read from `domain2.com`

Comment: test.php on domain2.com

Comment: That's not what your code calls: `url:domain1.com/test.php,`

Comment: i create cookie on domain2.com and also retrive from domain2.com

Comment: Post the real code please. There's no way to see if your code doesn't work because you've e.g. forgotten to enclose your strings in quotes or because there's something else going on.

Comment: its real code i m testing this code now but i did not get any cookie details on domain2.php  page cookietest.php

Answer (score 0):

To create a cookie on domain2.php , you must make a GET request instead of POST request,

see the link below

[Cookie for a different domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6761415/how-to-set-a-cookie-for-another-domain)

Comment: I am using ajax to set cookie in test.php on domain2.com