# Sharing a file between two Azure App Services

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-appservice

I need two applications hosted on two Azure App Services to access one specific file(.xml). What is my best option? What are my options?

I am trying to implement: [Share authentication cookies among ASP.NET apps.](https://learn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/aspnet/core/security/cookie-sharing?view=aspnetcore-3.1)
Both apps have to access the COMMON KEY RING FOLDER with the key file.

One of the applications is ASP.NET MVC, the second one is ASP.NET Core, both run on .NET472

Edit:
I need a file to be accessible for two .net applications running as appservices. I will use C#/F# to read/write the file. The file must be on Azure.

Comment: have you explored https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/storage/files/?

Comment: @Sajeetharan - Azure Files mounts are only available when using containers. And Storage support is in Preview. Without knowing more about the OP's issue and specific needs, I don't think there's an answer to be had (aside from just suggesting various Azure services). Asking "what is my best option" is simply too broad and opinion-soliciting.

Comment: Thank you both. Edited and added what are my options.

Comment: Have you looked at publishing the desired xml file to a storage account and set up managed identity access for both app services to access said storage account to retrieve the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recomend you to use an Azure Blob Storage and read the xml from there.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-dotnet

Comment: This might be the answer. I have found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46456830/how-can-i-share-cookie-authentication-across-apps-in-azure-with-net-core

I will try it.

Comment: I dont know why and who downwoted your answer but storage account with blob worked perfectly. Thank you. Problem solved.

Comment: Don't worry man! Maybe i should have given a more elaborate answer but I'm happy that I helped you.