# Cookies in JS and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, cookies

I have 2 virtual hosts and I want to set Cookie on the one of them with JS:

```
var CSRF = Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15) + Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15);
$(".form-token").text(CSRF);
document.cookie = "CSRFToken=" + CSRF;
```

And then I want to try fetch this on the other host with PHP.  But
`var_dump($_COOKIE);` outputs just `_ga` variable.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: how are you posting?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6761415/how-to-set-a-cookie-for-another-domain

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot share cookies between two hosts that are at the same level of the tld (eg two subdomains), you can only share cookies from a higher level.

Eg, a cookie set on `first.exemple.com` cannot be read on `second.exemple.com`.

But if you do it from the higher level it can work: a cookie set on `.exemple.com` (while being on `exemple.com`) can be read on both `first.exemple.com` and `second.exemple.com`.

1. It has to be set while on higher domain (the user must be on a page of `exemple.com`, not on one of the subdomains), 
   and
2. the cookie domain must include the leading dot (a cookie set on `exemple.com` cannot be read by subdomains, but one set on `.exemple.com` can)

Make good note that `www.exemple.com` is not the same as `exemple.com`

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I'm not sure that I understand right the sentence about dot at the start.
I'm setting cookie on the "test.server" and trying to fetch them on the "upload.test.server" but it doesn't work.

Comment: Set the cookie on `.test.server`, with a leading dot. Eg: `document.cookie = "csrf=123456;domain=.test.server"`