# Set cookie for users browser when he access my website through another website

Tags: php, web, cookies, cookiestore

Is there any way to store a cookie in a users browser when he access my website through another website?

Example:

I have website a.com

User sends a request using  http://b.com and I'd like to set a cookie for http://a.com with this request.

Is it possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set a cookie for another domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6761415/how-to-set-a-cookie-for-another-domain)

Comment: *"I have website a.com ... and I'd like to set a cookie for http://a.com"* ... sounds perfectly normal... what exactly do you mean by *"User sends a request using http://b.com"*? Do you want a website you don't control to set the cookie for your site? Or do you simply want to set a cookie, on your own site, holding referral data?

Comment: "you want a website you don't control to set the cookie for your site" that's what I want. I've made some research and figured that's quite impossible (the way i saw it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is create a PHP script which sets a cookie but does not output anything. Then you can include this script using for example `<img>` or `<script>` tags. As soon as the browser tries to load that URL, it will set the cookies you specify in the header (given the fact third website cookies aren't blocked in the browser).

Then the cookie which is set is accessible by any page on a.com

Answer (score 0):

The easiest: Include a resource **img src="//a.com/setCookie.php" width="1" height="1"** into the content of **//b.com**

Comment: Thank you for your response. Unfortunately i don't have access to b.com  
In fact,  b.com could be any website

Comment: Then you can't do what you want. This would be a major security issue.