# Can I specify and set http-only cookie for another domain?

Tags: go, cookies, browser, oauth

Say I have a service that has two domains

```
app.myapp.com
api.myapp.com
```

My app does the whole OAuth/OpenID flow.

```
app.myapp.com/oauth
app.myapp.com/oauth/callback
```

In the `/callback` I set the `accessToken` as an http-only cookie on the current domain (`app.myapp.com`).

I have an assortment of microservices that live on `api.myapp.com`, all of which require an `accessToken` to work.

In the `/callback` stage of the OAuth flow, can I specify the other domain in my http-only cookie?

I am using Go + Gin

```
c.SetCookie(
    "accessToken", 
    accessToken, 
    3600, 
    "/", 
    "", 
    false, 
    true,
)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set a cookie for another domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6761415/how-to-set-a-cookie-for-another-domain)

Comment: If it's not possible to set the cookie on the second domain, how would you solve the above issue?

Answer (score 1):

Well, it depends. In general, no, you cannot set cookies for a different domain.

But you can set cookies for all subdomains of a domain you "control" (read RFC 6265 and publicsuffix.org for details) by setting the Domain attribute of a cookie.