# ASP.NET MVC: How to plant a session cookie in a redirection from the controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, redirect, session-cookies

I'm trying to redirect from inside a MVC controller to a different external URL, only adding a session cookie that I'd be able to access after redirection.

I've been checking tens of Stackoverflow's questions and more, only found old or irrelevant answers, or with different technologies.

```
// GET: api/lem/fst?url=xxx
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Get([FromQuery]string url)
        {
            var uri = new UriBuilder(url);
            var cookieOptions = new CookieOptions
            {
                Domain = uri.Host,
            };
            HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append("key123", "value123", cookieOptions);
            return Redirect(uri.ToString());
        }
```

For example, if I send a GET to https://.../api/lem/fst?url=www.google.com, 
I can see the cookie in the Set-Cookie response header from my server. 
Also, redirection works fine, while I can't see the cookie anywhere in the request or response from google.

Thanks!

Comment: You cannot write cookies for another domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6761443/7516160

Your code works fine: if it's the same domain then cookie from Get response is stored in cookie inventory and send (in request) to redirected url.

<del>For testing host two seperate web apps on your local machine. For example redirect from localhost:50324 to localhost:47232.</del>

Comment: Localhost with different ports isn't a good example; the port number is not part of the hostname as far as cookies are concerned.