# Set cookies to another domain by ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cookies, setcookie

I have a problem, when I try to set cookies in controller it is not works

```
  def test
    cookies["test"] = {

        :value => 'a yummy cookie',
        :expires => 1.year.from_now,
        :domain => 'domain.com'
    }
  end
```

But if I delete **:domain => 'domain.com'**
It is set to my domain "localhost:3000", I neet set my cookies to another domain. Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set a cookie for another domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6761415/how-to-set-a-cookie-for-another-domain)

Comment: @Eyeslandic nope, I dont know php )

Comment: @AzBezt, that has nothing to do with it, the answer there clearly states you cannot set a cookie on another domain, that would be one giant security hole.

Comment: You don't need to know PTP to understand "It is not possible".

Answer (score -1):

**You cannot set cookies for another domain.**