# Setting cookie with domain as client host in a cross origin request

Tags: node.js, xml, cookies, cross-domain

Can a server(example2.com) set a cookie to a client(example1.com) with domain as 'example1.com' when an api call is made from example1.com to example2.com

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to set cookies from one domain to another because if this happens there will be a lot of flaw in security.

You need to get example2.com to set the cookie. If example1.com redirect the user to example2.com/setcookie.php?example3=value

The setcookie script could contain the following to set the cookie and redirect to the correct page on example2.com

```
<?php
    setcookie('example1', $_GET['example3']);
    header("Location: example2.com/landingpage.php");
?>
```

For more visit:

> [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6761415/how-to-set-a-cookie-for-another-domain#:~:text=Setting%20cookies%20for%20another%20domain,encode%20this%20into%20the%20url.&text=You%20can't%2C%20at%20least,be%20a%20nasty%20security%20risk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6761415/how-to-set-a-cookie-for-another-domain#:%7E:text=Setting%20cookies%20for%20another%20domain,encode%20this%20into%20the%20url.&text=You%20can%27t%2C%20at%20least,be%20a%20nasty%20security%20risk).

There is good discussion on similar topic.