# Should I create cookie for two different domains

Tags: reactjs, babeljs

I am creating cookies in react using "react-cookie". I want to create same cookie for two different domains. Is this possible?

```
 cookies.set("WebTimeClock", result.result, {
                    expires: new Date(dateTime),
                    path: "/",
                    //domain: "inn-flow-v2-dev.azurewebsites.net",
                    domain: "localhost",
                    sameSite:false,
                  });
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set a cookie for another domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6761415/how-to-set-a-cookie-for-another-domain)

Comment: Yes! Thanks @barzin.A