# Cookies are not being set in cross origin production

Tags: node.js, heroku, cookies, next.js

I have my backend deployed on heroku and my frontend deployed on vercel for ssr. Cookies were being set in dev on my local machine.

cors settings:

```
app.use(
    cors({
      origin: process.env.CORS_ORIGIN, //my deployed frontend https://kreddit.vercel.app
      credentials: true,
    })
```

Heroku uses a proxy so I have this too

`app.set("trust proxy", 1);`

session settings:

```
cookie: {
        maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365 * 10, // 10 years
        httpOnly: true,
        secure: __prod__, // cookie only works in https
        sameSite: "none", // csrf
        domain: __prod__ ? ".kreddit.vercel.app" : undefined,
      },
```

my apollo client settings for frontend:
`credentials: "include"`

my request and response:

[image: request and response headers]

cookies:

[image]

The cookie is received but not being set and the cookies storage remains empty. What's going wrong here? Thanks in advance

Comment: You cannot set cookies for another domain, see [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6761443/10577550).

Comment: @nflaig That is my frontend domain

Comment: it does not really matter who owns the domain if the backend is running on a different domain than the frontend you cannot set cookies

Comment: @nflaig what should i do in this case then?

Comment: In the post I linked are some workarounds but I have not used those myself. A proper solution would be to run both on the same domain e.g. frontend on `example.com` and backend on `api.example.com`. This allows to set cookies with a wildcard such as `.example.com`