# Is there a way to save data to a client website on another domain with cookie?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Is there a way to save data to a client website on another domain so like `http://192.168.1.111:3000`.
I dont know how to do it I used `cookie-parser` like this `res.cookie("cookie", "hello");`. Only if the domain name is localhost that is the time the cookie is getting through.
The client is not getting the cookie and it is saying that the response status is 301.It is getting the cookie in the response headers but it is saying was not received over a secure connection. Thanks and Appreciate your help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set a cookie for another domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6761415/how-to-set-a-cookie-for-another-domain)