# Nextjs and ASP.NET Core Web API (Azure) - Cookies not being set to browser #50451

Tags: reactjs, cookies, next.js, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an ASP.NET Core Web API hosted on Azure with the link https://socialchainapi.azurewebsites.net/.

And NextJS app hosted on https://socialchain-client-api.vercel.app/
The problems:

I am trying to append cookies from the back-end as below - cookies options:

```
HttpOnly = true, Expires = refreshTokenExpiryDate, IsEssential = true, 
Secure = true, SameSite = SameSiteMode.None,
```

Appending the cookies from an `HttpPost` method :

```
Response.Cookies.Append("refreshToken", verifyResult.Value.User.RefreshToken, cookieOptionsRefreshToken); 
Response.Cookies.Append("accessToken", verifyResult.Value.AccessToken, cookieOptionsAccessToken);

var verifyResponse = new VerifyResponse(verifyResult.Value.User.AccountAddress, verifyResult.Value.AccessToken); 
return Ok(verifyResponse);
```

In the frontend (NextJS) I am receiving the cookies with no problem as below, but it is not set in the cookies storage.

Network response screenshot:

[Network response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ms9p0.png)

Console (no errors) screenshot:

[Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ilhYX.png)

Browser cookies storage screenshot:

[Cookies store](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHoO1.png)

Comment: "Cookies created as a part of response of network calls are also listed, but only for calls that happened while the tool is open."

Comment: @AndyRay what do you mean by that, did not understand sorry ?!

Comment: That's from the documentation of the Firefox inspector storage tab. Also, are your API and site are on different domains?

Comment: @AndyRay Aha ok, yes they are on different domains, thats why I am specifying (SameSite = SameSiteMode.None)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set a cookie for another domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6761415/how-to-set-a-cookie-for-another-domain)