# Facebook Connect API Work Flow behind the scene

Tags: authentication, facebook

I have visited a [site](http://www.slideshare.net/) . I have observed that When I am not logged in Facebook it ask for connect to facebook to download file. After that I have authenticated their Application. Now Whenever I logging in to Facebook and open this site it automatically detect that I am login in Facebook without any authentication.

I want to know that how it can identify that I am logged in Facebook? Can anybody suggest any good artical which shows the workflow of FaceBook conntect authetication behind the scene?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Authorization and Authentication](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/). Slideshare shares login state with facebook.com via the session cookie on your browser.

> The Facebook JavaScript SDK allows your users to register and sign-in
>   to your site using their Facebook accounts. This is done by sharing
>   the logged in user state between http://www.facebook.com/ and your
>   site. A Facebook user remains logged in to your site as long as they
>   are logged in to Facebook and there is a valid access token for your
>   app.

Comment: Thanks, I have review this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4701922/how-does-facebook-set-cross-domain-cookies-for-iframes-on-canvas-pages. I want to know that how they can shares a cookies. And how they know that only particular user is logged in.