# How to apply affiliation cookies through browser extension without redirect?

Tags: redirect, cookies, google-chrome-extension, browser-extension, affiliate

I'm currently working on a browser extension project for an affiliate marketing business. Affiliate marketing usually works by setting tracking cookies on click to identify the referrer in case an article is bought on the partner's website and rewards the referrer afterwards.

**How can some browser extensions "activate cashback" or "activate affiliation" without having the user to go through a redirect page? How can they apply all the tracking cookies with no apparent redirection?**

Options I considered:

- Creating an API endpoint that would store an array of cookies set during the chain of redirection then applying them directly on the browser. Problem: some platforms use client script with URL matching to set cookies on landing on the partner's website.
- Maybe it has something to do with form posting hack: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4702110/7576507

Furthermore, how can one know that the tracking cookies have been well set?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that these browser extensions create a tab using a standard affiliate link without focusing it.

Once it is completely loaded (DOM, external scripts etc...), they close it and display on the main tab that tracking has been activated.