# Automatic cookie single sign on on multiple domains - like google

Tags: cookies, dns, single-sign-on

I don't understand how google achieve the following mechanism of single sign on:

1. I login in gmail for example (I suppose this creates a cookie withmy authorization)
2. I open a new tab and direct type the url of "youtube"
3. Then I enter youtube logged in.

How can this second site detect that I've already been logged in.
They are different domains. Youtube can't read the cookie of Gmail.

All the solutions I've read about Single sign on don't allow this. The client always ask permission to a central login app.
In my example YouTube doesn't know I am the same user logged in Gmail (actually it does know, but I don't understand how)

Note that I type the url of "youtube" by hand. I don't clic the youtube icon from the upper toolbar of gmail (In that case gmail may pass some auth params through the url for example).

Comment: Maybe the answer is in this SO question?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44509/single-sign-on-across-multiple-domains

Comment: Were you able to find out how they do this? I am stumped because I have been looking at firebug and if I am signed in at `google.com`, going to `youtube.com` never redirects to something like `sso.google.com`. It somehow magically knows that you are logged on.

Comment: Did you find it how it works?

Comment: I have been looking for the answer to this for over a year,  I get some pointers to SAML, but it is basically the same thing you explained, the IDP stores the cookies and users have to be at least redirected to the IDP web page for the cookie to be read. In youtube there is no redirection happening.

Comment: @James Okpe George you can not see the redirection with your eyes . You need to use web debugger

Answer (score 22):

The cookies are set on specific domains. Ex:

```
setcookie(name,value,expire,path,domain)
```

When you log in on gmail, before "mail.google.com", you have been redirected to "accounts.google.com" then to "mail.google.com" so the cookies are on "accounts.google.com" too.

In this case, the domain is "accounts.google.com" and the path is "/" (the home path).

When you request "www.youtube.com" then you click on "connection" it requests
"accounts.google.com" fast so you can't see this redirection and checks if you have cookies on "accounts.google.com". If so, it checks if the cookies are valid and not expired, or user not banned... Then it redirects you to "www.youtube.com/signin?loginthisSession=Sessionid". This request contains the value of the of sessionid cookie catched from the cookies of "accounts.google.com".

In the last step, "www.youtube.com" logs you and set its own cookie on the domain "www.youtube.com" and saves them.

So the trick is on the 302 HTTP redirect.

**Update**

i do not know why people keep mentioning `iframe` take a look at the date whene this questions was posted on `2016` google was not using then `iframe` as i mentioned the capture of web traffic as you can see `SetSID` wich means set the cookie of SESSION_ID from `accounts.google.dz(com)` then redirects to `youtube.com` it can not be used trought `iframe` `differant domains` `security measure` you can not be redirected from domain to domain trought iframe `neither` please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2117248/setting-cookie-in-iframe-different-domain) before posting

[image]

Comment: How the redirection is implemented without we see on Firebug?

Comment: Is that how it actually works? Including the session ID in the URL is usually considered insecure (yes _it is_ encrypted if HTTPS is used, but it can be logged by servers, proxies, browser history or leaked by the HTTP referrer header).

Comment: @chanchal118
please open your eyes on this screenshot or just do it via proxy/httpfox and you will see 
http://i.imgur.com/aDIcYJb.png

Comment: @SilverlightFox 
please open your eyes on this screenshot or just do it via proxy/httpfox and you will see http://i.imgur.com/aDIcYJb.png

Comment: @K3rnel31 Is this screen shot taken while logging into youtube?

Comment: @chanchal118 Exactly , taken yesterday at same time , do it by yourself and you will see :) , those requests are all from 302 , each one redirect to the other , till ends up at youtube.com

Comment: @K3rnel31 Do you see any request to youtube when you logged into gmail?

Comment: @chanchal118 yeah gmail in this case its youtube , same thing , before you got logged in to gmail , u will be steped from accounts.google.com , then same process , untill you end up at gmail , the question was montioned gmail , but basicly its not gmail who made youtube loggedin , its accounts.google.com what made gmail logged in , then youtube logged in ...

Comment: @chanchal118 @k3rnel31 If you go from gmail to youtube it doesn't do any redirects. It seems to use an iframe as suggested by @pedrofb in [his answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11434866/automatic-cookie-single-sign-on-on-multiple-domains-like-google#answer-37405389), if I switch the frame in the console from <top> to one of the <iframe>'s and check the location, one of them has a host of `accounts.google.com` with relevant sign in data in the `search` field

Comment: @sgtpepper43 question is asked on 2012 .. there was no iframe as i mentioned on the picture google was working by 302 redirect ..

Comment: Sure that's how it worked in 2012, but the comments I was responding to are from 2016, and in 2016, they were using iframes. The question was "how to do SSO across domains like google", not "how did google do SSO across domains in 2012". If a stack overflow post is to remain useful, it should stay updated.

Comment: Regarding your update, though, they were never _redirecting_ using iframes. They were most likely using the `postMessage` api, which allows you to push _anything_ you want between an iframe and the parent. Anything the website in the iframe has access to (cookies, local storage, etc) can be pushed to the parent with `postMessage`, as long as the parent is listening for it, as demonstrated here https://stackoverflow.com/a/37565692/2749072#answer-37565692

Comment: @SgtPepper43 you need to understand one thing , the question was about being signed in to youtube from gmail  domain redirection on the address bar wich you can never do it with iframe

Comment: @Hichem Reread the question, it has nothing to do with redirection. They're logged in to gmail, then they type in youtube.com, and they're automatically logged in *without any redirection*. And again, you really need to read about the `postMessage` api. You can do anything with iframes.

Answer (score 5):

Cookies and localStorage can be shared between domains using an intermediate domain. On the home page is embedded an "iframe ', which accesses cookies and sends messages to the main.

`mail.google.com` and `youtube.com` can share the cookies using  `accounts.google.es`. Open `Chrome->Inspect->Resources->Local storag`e and you will see in `accounts.google.com` the authentication token in JWT format.

I have detailed the technical steps in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37565692/6371459. Also take a look at https://github.com/Aralink/ssojwt to see an implementation of a Single Sign On using JWT in a central domain

Comment: Note that adding iframe to share cookie between domain are called `3rd party cookie` and are being obsolete moving forward in new browser, check this: https://blog.chromium.org/2020/01/building-more-private-web-path-towards.html

Comment: Seems it will affect third party cookies that do not include the SameSite tag or do not use https. This affects tracking cookies but not the use explained in the answer and in no case to `localStorage`. The content is shared using `postMessage` between iframes that is a secure and accepted method

Answer (score 2):

Check this out.. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/106439/Single-Sign-On-SSO-for-cross-domain-ASP-NET-applic. 
The article consist explanation and sample of SSO cross domain.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember, if I am not wrong, cookies contains a specified field that contains the domain that can read and get such cookie. That is made in order to prevent certain web sites to read all your cookie list and make your own business. You should be able to see which kind of sites can 'see' your gmail cookie.

Correct me if I am wrong, this should compile the answer given regarding the SID and gmail-YouTube example..

Answer (score 0):

While evaluating this cross domain SSO topic, I have come up with possible a new SSO synchronization flow using **cookie with timestamp**. Although it is not a flow used by Google, I think this flow is possible to implement for system with limited number of domains.

This flow do not use `3rd party cookie`

This is going to be a long post :)

### domains

To make an example, let say we have these domains for our example *pet forums*:

- https://account.domain1.com (For SSO Login)
- .domain1.com (e.g. https://cat.domain1.com)
- .domain2.com (e.g. https://dog.domain2.com)
- .domain3.com (e.g. https://rabbit.domain3.com)

### Change to https://account.domain1.com:

- Add https://account.domain2.com and https://account.domain3.com, route both host name traffic to the server hosting https://account.domain1.com

### Login Steps:

1. User go to `dog.domain2.com`, user have not sign in yet.
2. User click the Login button in `dog.domain2.com`
3. User get redirect to `account.domain1.com` for login

   - This step can be any Login protocol, OAuth, OIDC, SAML, CAS, etc
   - So, it is important for user to be redirected back to original page after login
   - Let say this https://account.domain1.com?redirect_uri=https://dog.domain2.com
   - `redirect_uri` as in the URL to go back after login success
4. User Input username & password, login success
5. **New step**, before redirect back to  https://dog.domain2.com, set cookies on all domains

   1. Redirect browser to https://accounts.domain2.com?...
   2. Set a cookie on the `.domains2.com` domain (More on the cookie value later)
   3. Redirect browser to https://accounts.domain2.com?...
   4. Set a cookie on the `.domains3.com` domain
   5. Redirect browser to https://accounts.domain1.com?...
   6. Set a cookie on the `.domains1.com` domain
   7. Redirect back to original flow
6. Redirect user back to their original service, i.e. https://dog.domain2.com

Now, right after login flow **we have cookies over all 3 domains**. Any of our service (e.g. https://cat.domain1.com / https://dog.domain2.com / https://rabbit.domain2.com ) can access this cookie under their own domain.

### Cookie Content

- The content of the cookie, should allows for any webpage to look at it, and determine if SSO sync is needed
- Different types of cookie content can be stored, including

  - Boolean indicate user logined or not
  - User ID
  - Expired At timestamp

#### Boolean indicate user logined or not

- Storing `have_user_login` = true / false have sync issue
- Suppose `User A` login, visit  https://cat.domain1.com, `User A` Logout, and `User B` login
- Now, from https://cat.domain1.com standpoint, no sync is needed
- However, https://cat.domain1.com is storing `User A` instead of `User B`, hence the sync issue.

#### User ID

- While it is tempting to just stored the `user_id` on those cookie, and let all the domain to see them and set the user accordingly.

  - This is way too dangerous, since the cookie is set at the parent domain,
  - if any of the website under your domain been hacked, **impersonation** might happen (Copying any of the `user_id`, pasting it to their own browser cookie).

#### Expired At Timestamp

- What I suggest, is for the cookie value to set as the **SSO expired time**, and set the type as **session** cookie, this have the following benefits:

  - An expired time have minimal security impact if leaked / altered
  - Our website can check the expired time to know if user need to relogin
  - As for why session cookie, is for when user close them browser, and tried to login again, the cookie will be deleted hence logout the user as well
- Any webpage that use the SSO, should also stored a cookie themselves with the same expired time

  - There will be cases that, `User A` Login, visit https://cat.domains1.com Then `User B` Login
  - Since `User A` and `User B` will have a different login expired time, storing and compare that timestamp will tell the user to sync with SSO again

### Example checking implement for your service

E.g. On https://cat.domains1.com, you can add this to the top of your page load

```php
<?php
$sso_expired_time = $_COOKIE["sso_expired_time "] ?? 0;
$website_expired_time = $_COOKIE["website_expired_time "] ?? 0;

if( (int) $sso_expired_time  < time() || $sso_expired_time  !== $website_expired_time ) {
    // User not sync, perform sync
    setcookie("website_expired_time", $website_expired_time,0,"/", $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], true, true);
    // Redirect to https://account.domain1.com for Login
    // Or, Initiate the login sequence for your selected login protocol
    header("Location: https://account.domain1.com/.....") 
    exit;
}
// User is sync

// Page load success, continue other operation
```

### Logout

Login is very similar to Login, basically:

- Before logout goes through, redirect to all 3 domains just like login
- Remove the SSO cookie
- Continue the normal logout flow

### Pro and cons for the methods:

- Pro: All domain sync possible
- Pro: No need to relies on 3rd party cookie
- Cons: First time login longer (around 50ms longer)
- Cons: Customization on every website is needed for the sync to works

Comment: In this implementation if a domain is unavailable, it won't redirect to the next one and subsequent domains won't log in/out, right? Is there an easy way to go around that other than opening multiple tabs/popups for each domain?

Comment: You can check if the page is up or not using this image trick: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63897923/6463291.