Is there a service to share session between domains like google.com and youtube.com?
my goal is to share session between domains similar to what google.com and youtube.com achieves.
I implemented session between subdomains for my current employer. The company use Firebase. The login took a solid 3-6 seconds.
I plan to build a proof of concept to share session between domains.

User able to login with email and password.
User able to login with Google / Facebook / Apple.

Is there a service for that? or should I manage auth with custom back end?

Once you have implemented something and have a problem, post a question. Posts like this one might be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11434866/8016720

@JohnHanley wow the redirect is a really neat trick. It makes sense.
