# ASP.NET Unique Browser ID

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, browser, webforms

I have a single solution with multiple C# ASP.NET Web Forms projects. I want a way to identify a given browser so that each website can identifier that same browser. I need to do this from the C# Code-Behind code (not with the client code, like JavaScript). I also cannot use the Session because it isn't shared across websites. I don't think cookies are either.

For example, if a user logs onto Website1 and then logs onto Website2 with the same browser on the same computer, I want to be able to identify that. But if a user logs onto Website1 with Chrome and then Website1 with FireFox (regardless of whether it's on the same computer or not), I want to detect that as well.

If it makes any difference, I am using Azure to publish my web projects. So all websites will have similar domains (eg website1.azurewebsites.net and website2.azurewebsites.net).

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Would cookies work?

Comment: Yes, cookies would work. The purpose is essentially so that I can see if it's the same person on each website in order to have some shared data (shared settings, shared log in, etc) and to track activity across websites for a given user.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to track someone using the same browser on the same computer then use a cookie. If the websites have different domains you'll need to be clever because modern browsers have a lot of protection against what they see as tracking cookies. One option is using a [hidden interstitial page as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18664395/is-there-something-a-site-can-do-to-incorporate-third-party-cookies).

Your second scenario, a user accessing same site with different browsers, I suggest storing the user agent string (one of the request headers) and adding this to a login audit so you can build up a collection of different user agents used by a given user. There are libraries available for parsing user agent strings and extracting name, version, engine etc.

Between these two techniques and a bit of business logic you should get what you need. If you would like me to clarify any of this, let me know and I'll provide more detail.

Comment: I checked out that link. That seems to only be one you have one site hosted "within" (for lack of better words) another site via iFrame. That is not what I'm doing here. Also, I don't care about the same user but with different browsers. That's not a big deal to me. Normally a user will use the same browser for everything they do, so that's the more important case.