# how to set cookie from iframe and reach it from js

Tags: javascript, security, cookies, xss, same-origin-policy

I want to load an iframe `cdnsite.com` to a site called `differentsite.com`

I want to set some credentials to a cookie called `CDN_CREDENTS` in my `cdnsite.com` iframe

Also `differentsite.com` will implement my script `cdnsite.com/cdn.js`,

1. What I want to know is that, because the cookie is set in `cdnsite.com` can I read `CDN_CREDENTS` cookies from headers when loading `cdnsite.com/cdn.js` from headers.
2. Also can I set cookies when `cdnsite.com/cdn.js` is loading from my backend via headers, with `cdnsite.com` domain

thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting cookie in iframe - different Domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2117248/setting-cookie-in-iframe-different-domain)

Comment: @Saeed Setting cookie in iframe - different Domain
I will set cookie to my own iframe domain, which is not different domain, I want to read my domain cookie from header, it is different

Comment: DUe to " cross-origin frame policy" I don't think it is possible... basically, if an Iframe domain is different form the parent domain, they cannot communicate.