# Safari 13+ blocks cross domain cookie in iframe [Works on safari 12 , 11, and 10]

Tags: cookies, iframe, browser, safari

In safari versions lower than 12, when there was an cookie disabled issue , i used to redirect website to cross domain website and created cookie there. Then redirected website back to web page containing iframe. But unfortunately it does not work in safari 13+. It blocks cookies. 
But it works in private window.

It would be great if anyone can help me with below issues.

Comment: I'm in the same boat. Even if the cookie already exists for the framed in page, it's still blocked. If I load it the framed in page as the parent, the cookies are accessible.

I was hoping maybe a CORS setting would help, but I haven't found anything on it.

Comment: I didn't get any solutions yet. I am just detecting safari 13 and redirecting user to a separate page or showing some alert. I will update here once i will get some working solutions.  @HoangTrung

Comment: I haven't tested this yet, but I assume the reason is they have implemented the same change Chrome has implemented in the upcoming version where SameSite must be set to None and HTTPS must be enabled - https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5088147346030592.

There is a note in that link as well about a bug affecting OSX/iOS where SameSite=None are treated as Strict despite being set. In any case I think the 'bounce' method will no longer work unfortunately to pre-create the cookie.

Comment: I fixed this and post it here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/60924467/2360774 Hope it help.

Comment: @HoangTrung your solution is good for Chrome. It does NOT work in Safari. Safari just block any cookies from iframe